# using custom filter BeforeAction in .net2.0 Monorail setop not always firing

Tags: c#-2.0, castle-monorail

I have made a custom filter that is to fire on every action(request).  So what the issue seems to be is that thou the first time the action runs when the user refreshes it never runs again.  It's like it's cached or something.  I does fire the filter the first time so the code is working(-ish) but it's the secound loadin of the page that is killing me. here is basicly the code.

```
        using MonoRailHelper;
        namespace evergreen.Controllers
        {

            public class loggedinFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute
            {
                public loggedinFilterAttribute() : base ( ExecuteEnum.BeforeAction, typeof(AuthenticationFilter))
                {

                    String username = Authentication.authenticate();
                    // save user in database
                    authUser[] authUser_list = ActiveRecordBase<authUser>.FindAll();
                    authUser temp = null;
                    foreach (authUser authUser in authUser_list)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authUser.Nid) && authUser.Nid.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
                        { temp = authUser; }
                    }
                    temp.Logedin = true;
                    temp.LastActive = DateTime.Now;
                    temp.Save();

                }
            }


            [loggedinFilter] 
            [Layout("default"), Rescue("generalerror")]
            public abstract class BaseController : MonoRailHelper.HelperBaseController

            {
                function a bunch
            }
            }
        }
```

loggedinFilter is that is to fire and the   temp.LastActive = DateTime.Now; does move up in the db as you go to "new" pages here but it's when you go back.. no change occures.

anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks for the help.. Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not perform authentication in a filter attribute constructor.

Instead, follow the [instructions for creating a filter](http://docs.castleproject.org/MonoRail.Creating-a-filter.ashx): implement IFilter (your auth logic comes here), then apply the filter to the controller using the FilterAttribute. You can *then* (if you want) wrap the FilterAttribute in your own attribute implementation.

[More info about filters](http://docs.castleproject.org/MonoRail.Filters.ashx).

[Here's a Monorail auth filter that uses ActiveRecord](https://github.com/andypike/Castlecasts/blob/master/Website/src/AndyPike.Castlecasts.Website/Filters/AuthenticationFilter.cs), you could use it for reference.

Comment: Hello thanks, the first link I saw before, but well it's just not clear.  poor docs imho but.. https://github.com/andypike/Castlecasts/blob/master/Website/src/AndyPike.Castlecasts.Website/Filters/AuthenticationFilter.cs that was perfect to guide me on how.  Thanks for the help..